# ubuntu 20.04 cannot suspend

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend

pc: xps 15 9500
os: dual boot ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10

My ubuntu updated at some point from 18 to 20.
Soon after I am not able to put into suspend anymore.

When I suspend screen goes dark, keyboard backlight is still on for a few moments

and then it goes all dark for a second, after which the keyboard light turns on again and I get this screen...

[image]

after that I cannot turn it on again without turning it off
weirdly, the power button works, meaning, if a press it while in this state,
the pc turns off after 20-30s.

I searched and tried different things like changing the nvidia drivers, changing some grub configs... but nothing helped and the behavior stays the same, except when I pick nvidia-drivers-460 under software and updates -> additional drivers, after which the computer turns off / crashes completely when I try to suspend